# "bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable" error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fork, git-bash

When I open `git bash` I get these messages:

```
      2 [main] bash (40164) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1301410/0x12A1410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] bash 45888 fork: child -1 - forked process 40164 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
```

I also tried `ulimit -a` and got:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

And found this command in another similar question `ulimit -Sn unlimited && ulimit -Sl unlimited` and got this result:

```
bash: ulimit: -l: invalid option
ulimit: usage: ulimit [-SHabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT] [limit]
```

Comment: What happened when you searched for cygwin1.dll? Do you have the most recent version and only the most recent version?

Comment: @B.Shefter I searched for that but seems I don't have such file

Comment: That's odd, because in that case I would have expected a different error message, something like, "The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer." Regardless, I'd try reinstalling cygwin (and rebooting).

Comment: @B.Shefter: I downloaded a newer version and installed and rebooted but again the same problem!

Comment: Hmm. Because you installed a different version of cygwin, I'd try another search for cygwin1.dll--it's possible that there are now multiple versions of that file, as the error message indicates.